# create control with properties within it

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have control something like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "AQLevelMeter.h"

    #import "AQPlayer.h"
    #import "AQRecorder.h"


@interface SpeakHereController : NSObject {

    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem*   btn_record;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem*   btn_play;
    IBOutlet UILabel*           fileDescription;
    IBOutlet AQLevelMeter*      lvlMeter_in;

    AQPlayer*                   player;
    AQRecorder*                 recorder;
    BOOL                        playbackWasInterrupted;
    BOOL                        playbackWasPaused;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem     *btn_record;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem     *btn_play;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UILabel             *fileDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   AQLevelMeter        *lvlMeter_in;

@property (readonly)            AQPlayer            *player;
@property (readonly)            AQRecorder          *recorder;
@property                       BOOL                playbackWasInterrupted;
@property                       BOOL                isReport;
@property CFStringRef           recordFilePath;


- (IBAction)record: (id) sender;
- (IBAction)play: (id) sender;
-(void) InitializeThePlayer;

@end
```

as we can see I added many properties  like

```
   @property                        BOOL                isReport;
    @property CFStringRef           recordFilePath;
```

then I created uiview contains this control

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SpeakHereController;

@interface SpeakHereViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet SpeakHereController *controller;
}
```

Now I want to access the properties of the control object so I say

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {



    [self ReportDirectory];

    [controller setIsReport:self.iSReport ];
    //controller.isReport = self.iSReport ;

    [controller setRecordFilePath:(CFStringRef) self.DICOMpath];

    //controller.recordFilePath = ;


}
```

the problem is that at the lines

```
[controller setIsReport:self.iSReport ];
[controller setRecordFilePath:(CFStringRef) self.DICOMpath];
```

there is warning say that

```
warning: no '-setIsReport:' method found
```

I made

```
@synthesize isReport; 
@synthesize recordFilePath;
```

also if I replaced  @class SpeakHereController; by #import  "SpeakHereController.h" it raise a lot of errors , U can download the sample code from apple

and if I said controller.isReport = self.iSReport ; it raise error request for member 'isReport' in something not a structure or union

My question is how to call the properties in this control , am I missing something

Best regards

I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of SpeakHereViewController.m you will need

```
import "SpeakHereController.h"
```

Otherwise when SpeakHereViewController.m is compiled, it is completely unaware of what methods and properties your `SpeakHereController` class has

It should run fine even with the warning because the property does exist. However, I agree with you that the warning needs to be dealt with.

Comment: I use @class SpeakHereController; is it enough

Comment: No, the @class line prevents an error in the .h file. Have you tried what I suggested? Let us know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Maudicus i am suffering through the same issue.i am using speakViewController class as NSObject as it is used in speakHere sample ,But not able to acess the methodes from other class how to acheive this!

Answer (score 0):

You should synthesize those properties in .m file.

The syntax is like:

```
@synthesize isReport, recordFilePath;
```